# Can you control how the tasks are executed in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have built a pipeline with 4 tasks

- Task 1 Builds a VM
- Task 2 Add a Data Disk
- Task 3 Add a Second Data Disk
- Task 4 Add a Third Data Disk

However, if I only want Task 1 and Task 2 to execute how can I skip Task 3 and 4? For example, if the user only wants 1 Data Disk. I know they can be disabled manually but is there a way to automate this based on a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every stage, job and task has a `condition` property. You can [use a condition expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to decide which tasks to run and when. You can reference variables in such expressions. By [promoting these variables to a "Queue time variable"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#allow-at-queue-time) you can let a user control these.

Make sure you prepend each condition with `succeeded()` to make the previous steps have completed succesfully.

```
condition: and(succeeded(), gt(variables.Disks, 2))
```

See:

- [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops)
- [Specify Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
- [Define Variables - Allow at queue time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#allow-at-queue-time)

Comment: can i use a pipleine variable ? eg if $(datadisk1) = "y" ?

Comment: The example shows how to use a variable. Ether use `variables['name']` or `variables.name`.

Comment: Example: `condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.datadisk1, 'y'))`

Comment: can you use variables declared in the pipeline variables , where are you declaring the variable datadisk1?

Comment: Wherever you want.  To allow them to be set at queue time though, you'll need so define them on the `Variables` button/screen on the Edit Pipeline screen.

Comment: ok it worked but to note in the inline scripts variables are referred to as $(datadisk1) but in the custom condition they don't use the brackets and are just referred to as $datadisk